# Use variable out of scope in java

Tags: java, scope, handler

hello I want to use a variable and catch some data in another inner scope and use it for other place in main scope but my problem is when I setup my variable in inner scope, it will be forget out of scope.

```
public class ...{
   static TextView txt1;
   static String i="Z0";

   static Handler UIupdater = new Handler() {
      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {              
        //some data
            i ="Z1";
      }
   };

   txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
   txt1.setText(i+"");//still get "Z0"

}
```

I want to see "Z1", but it shows "Z0".
what is the solution?

Comment: Are you sure the handler is being called?

Comment: Welcome to SO! If your question is directly related to a language, please tag it with the language.

Comment: yes i used handler my codes are there too

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the line `txt1.setText(i+"");` is run while the class is being loaded, whereas the line `i ="Z1";` is not run until the handler actually receives a message — too late to affect `txt1`.

The solution is either to move or copy `i = "Z1"` to a part of the program that is run earlier, or to move or copy `txt1.setText(i+"");` to a part of the program that is run later. For example:

```
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      i = "Z1";
      txt1.setText(i);
  }
```

Comment: handler is always running( it catch data from my socket) so "i" should be "Z1". and txt1.setText(i); is just for monitor and show, actually it will be use for another function that is impossible to define in handleMessage(){

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        public class ...{
       static TextView txt1;
       static String i="Z0";

       static Handler UIupdater = new Handler() {
          @Override
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {              
            //some data
                i ="Z1";

           txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
           txt1.setText(i+"");//still get "Z0"

          }
       };

}
```

Comment: I answered for this for previous answer in addition txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1); line can't be define in HandlerMessage